# AdventureWorks2012 DB - how the password validated in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I had seen the below thread which explains how the password validated in C#.

[Sql Password validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815872/adventureworks2012-db-how-the-password-was-stored-and-how-the-password-validat)

**I want to do the same in sql stored procedure.**

```
select * from Person.Password
```

[image: Sql password]

how to validate the password against the values of password salt and password hash? which algorithm its using to encrypt the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE CheckPassword
@username VARCHAR(20),
@password varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN

IF (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), HASHBYTES('sha1', @password), 1)) <> (select PassColumn from myTable WHERE myUser = @username )
BEGIN 
    print 'Password Matches'
END
else
    print 'Password does not match'
END
```

You can follow the [MSDN: How to Validate Passwords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545760(v=cs.70).aspx) which says:

> **To validate a password**
>
> 1. Create a function called VerifyPassword that retrieves a user's
>      password from the Profiles System.
> 2. Hash the password and compare it to the user's entered password.
> 3. Inside the VerifyPassword function, create a CommerceContext object
>      and call the GetProfile method.
> 4. Retrieve the Password property from the UserProfile property
>      collection.
> 5. Create a function called VerifyHashedPassword that compares the
>      user's entered password against a hashed password. This function
>      will use the HashPassword function that is described in How to Hash
>      Passwords.

Comment: I want to validate in a Stored procedure.

Comment: @user833985:- Updated my answer. Please check now!